# Prevent default action on all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a HTML form designer - user can place input elements in a grid on a page which will then be saved to a database and the finished form will be useable by other users.

Now all of this actually works already, but I've hit a fairly trivial, yet annoying issue - since I need to use the actual input elements in the code so the layout appears correctly during design, user can type in textfields, change the values of checkboxes etc., but none of that actually get saved, so it's quite confusing. Now the form designer allows for the elements to be enabled/disabled, so disabling all elements on the page would be even worse.

My question is: Can you completely disable default actions of all input elements (writing text after clicking on text field, checking/unchecking checkboxes, that kind of stuff) in a simple manner? So far I've tried binding various events with jQuery's preventDefault, with no success. I know I could just react to stuff like keypresses and undo them, but that just seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: what kinds of input do you have? readonly is a option maybe?

Comment: Give the inputs the `disabled="disabled"` attribute or using jQuery `$('input').prop('disabled', true);`. You can use the readonly attribute aswell.

Comment: @Sergio : Oh. And I thought I can't find an answer because so few people ever needed such a thing, not because I'm a complete tool. Oh well, post it as an answer so I can give you your rep and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of inputs you have you could give the the `readonly` attribute. Either directly on the html or by jQuery `$("input").prop("readonly",true);`

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$("input").on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can place `change` in place of `click` for the radio and checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Consider your form has id :

```
<form id="test">

</form>
```

To disable all inputs :

```
$("#test :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Matches all input, textarea, select and button elements.

If you only want the  elements:

```
$("#test input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Cheers